# zsh: command not found: ampy

Tags: python, terminal, esp32

I just installed ampy with pip on MacOS (Big Sur). However, I keep getting this error message:

```
user@user ~ % ampy --help   
zsh: command not found: ampy
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

I am afraid there is something wrong with my PATH

If I run

```
user@server ~ % pip3 install --user adafruit-ampy           
Requirement already satisfied: adafruit-ampy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.8.dev19+g2443bfc)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from adafruit-ampy) (0.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from adafruit-ampy) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from adafruit-ampy) (7.1.2)
```

And my .bash_profile file is as follows:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages; export PATH
```

Additionally, I get this:

```
user@server ~ % PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; export PATH
user@server ~ % ampy --help
zsh: permission denied: ampy
user@server ~ % sudo ampy --help
sudo: ampy: command not found
```

Comment: You simply didn't install it, didn't install it correctly or it doesn't contain a program with that name. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please describe exactly what you did (like a [mcve]). Lastly, consider filing a bug ticket, because installation support isn't not the right topic for a programming forum as Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, you are on MacOS - that's a thing you may want to mention next time ;-) Then your "ampy" app should be located in: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages  What is the output of "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ampy --help"

Comment: Yes MacOS. Sorry for not mentioning it.
So here is what I get:

Comment: ```user@server ~ % sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ampy --help

Password:

sudo: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ampy: command not found
```

Comment: Locate your ampy (or adafruit-ampy)  installation and once you found it look in my answer below and alter the PATH variable accordingly.

Comment: Okay if i do a simple search of ampy on my mac I get this location ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/```
and for python 2.7
```/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ampy```

Comment: I updated my bash_profile as you can see above in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on MacOS, I altered my answer a bit...

After installation you can either add the path to ampy to your environment path by:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; export PATH
```

or add it to your shell_rc or you can create a symlink to ampy by:

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ampy /usr/local/bin/ampy
```

Then you should be able to do the `ampy --help`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I am sorry but yeah I am not the best when it comes to these issues. Basically now if I run this ```pip3 install --user adafruit-ampy``` I get the following (See I edited my question)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help, although sometimes it's not easy to understand what people are askign actually ;-) Did it help then?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately

Comment: Do "PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages; export PATH" Then you should be able to do "ampy --help" - add that to your bash_profile and you're set!

Comment: Just added the new line "PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages; export PATH" to my bash_profile however I still get the same error with command not found

Comment: Have you checked if the ampy app is there - I mean in the directory? Perhaps it has a different name on MacOS?

Comment: I have a folder for python3.8 and one for python2.7. I also have a file called ampy (terminal file, I do not know the specific name) at this location ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/ampy``` and for python2.7 ```/Users/gabrieleansaldo/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ampy```

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND: I had to apply the changes to my bash_profile with ```source ~/.bash_profile```

Comment: Nice buddy, if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted answer, so the question can be closed - thanks in advance